# Angular JS Defining a Variable with ngInit

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Basically I'm sending a variable from PHP to Angular JS.  I echo the PHP variables into the ng-init tag, and it renders properly (ng-init="listing=5;user=59").

```
<div id="content" ng-app="galleryApp" ng-controller="galleryController" 
    ng-init="listing=<?php echo $lid ?>;user=<?php echo $sessionUser ?>">
```

However, in my angular JS code, when I log the variables, they come up as undefined.

```
var galleryApp = angular.module('galleryApp', []);

function galleryController ($scope, $http, $log) {

    console.log($scope.listing);  // <-- undefined
    console.log($scope.user); // <-- undefined

    var postData = { listing : $scope.listing, user: $scope.user };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller's constructor function is called before `ng-init`.  If you think about it, the controller's `$scope` has to exist before `ng-init` can add things to it.

If you add a `$watch` to the properties on the controller's scope, if all is set up correctly, you should see it change:

```
function galleryController ($scope, $http, $log) {

    $scope.$watch('listing', function(value) { console.log(value); });
    $scope.$watch('user', function(value) { console.log(value); });

    var postData = { listing : $scope.listing, user: $scope.user };
```